# Position:absolute and bottom:0 is not working (div is not sticking to bottom and scrolling) when keyboard opens in iOS safari

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, angular, safari

I am implementing a chatbot where it has list of questions and answers which are scrollable and an absolute input which is fixed to bottom.Everything is working perfectly but when we focused on input and keyboard opened fixed input is scrolling and a gap is coming between keyboard and input in iPhone safari.

I have a parent container which has position:relative, height and width are 100%.

A scrollable div for question and answers which has overflow: auto and height:calc(100%-159px).

Finally input container which has position:absolute, bottom:0,z-index:999,width:100%.

Please find the attached images for reference, any help would be much appreciated.[image]

Comment: Use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`, this is the more correct way to make it sticked to the bottom.

Comment: @noChance I tried with position: fixed as well but didn’t work.

Comment: Ok, then it seems like your "parent container" is not having the full screen height. Could you add some of your html & css?

Comment: @noChance As I mentioned in the question my css looks like below

I have a parent container which has position:relative, height and width are 100%.

A scrollable div for question and answers which has overflow: auto and height:calc(100%-159px).

Finally input container which has position:absolute, bottom:0,z-index:999,width:100%.

Comment: Well, it's still not clear what is above your "parent container" and whether the two elements in the "parent container" are siblings or not..

Comment: above my parent container, there's a fixed toolbar. If you have any chance you can login to qa.shortlist.net.webportal/#/login and then hit https://qa.shortlist.net/webportal/#/job/1879/chatroom/951